# How to Decrypt or Decode for this JavaScript

Tags: javascript, encryption, decode

I'm trying to decrypt this code:

```
eval(unescape("%66%75%6E%63%74%69%6F%6E%20%68%70%5F%64%31%31%28%73%29%7B%76%61%72%20%6F%3D%22%22%2C%61%72%3D%6E%65%77%20%41%72%72%61%79%28%29%2C%6F%73%3D%22%22%2C%69%63%3D%30%3B%66%6F%72%28%69%3D%30%3B%69%3C%73%2E%6C%65%6E%67%74%68%3B%69%2B%2B%29%7B%63%3D%73%2E%63%68%61%72%43%6F%64%65%41%74%28%69%29%3B%69%66%28%63%3C%31%32%38%29%63%3D%63%5E%32%3B%6F%73%2B%3D%53%74%72%69%6E%67%2E%66%72%6F%6D%43%68%61%72%43%6F%64%65%28%63%29%3B%69%66%28%6F%73%2E%6C%65%6E%67%74%68%3E%38%30%29%7B%61%72%5B%69%63%2B%2B%5D%3D%6F%73%3B%6F%73%3D%22%22%7D%7D%6F%3D%61%72%2E%6A%6F%69%6E%28%22%22%29%2B%6F%73%3B%72%65%74%75%72%6E%20%6F%7D"));

eval(hp_d11(unescape("fmawoglv,upkvg*%25>qap%25%22)%22%25krv%22qpa? %25%22)]gfkvmp]wpn)%22%25ocekagfkvmp,hq %25+9")));
```

So far I'v decrypted the first part to this:

```
eval(unescape("function hp_d11(s){var o="",ar=new Array(),os="",ic=0;for(i=0;i<s.length;i++){c=s.charCodeAt(i);if(c<128)c=c^2;os+=String.fromCharCode(c);if(os.length>80){ar[ic++]=os;os=""}}o=ar.join("")+os;return o}"));
```

But I can't figure out the second part.
Can anybody help? Please?

Comment: This is a mess; Perhaps if you give us some context. Where did you get this code, what is it for/what should it do? How did you decrypt the first part, anyway?

Comment: `hp_d11` can't be found by Google. We really can't reverse engineer a function using its name alone.

Comment: `document.write('<scr' + 'ipt src="' +_editor_url+ 'magiceditor.js"');`

Answer (score 0):

This is an atempt of script injection, the result of this

```
hp_d11(unescape("fmawoglv,upkvg*%25>qap%25%22)%22%25krv%22qpa? %25%22)]gfkvmp]wpn)%22%25ocekagfkvmp,hq %25+9"))
```

will be a document.write with a script path.